# Microsoft graph: Invalid batch payload format

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to batch [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) a list of users, using the MS Graph Batch API following the [example from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp#batches-with-dependent-requests) but getting the error "Message: Invalid batch payload format."

```
// batch disable all users
var allUsers = await GraphHelper.client.Users.Request().Select("id").GetAsync();

var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
allUsers.Select(user =>
{
  var httpRequest = GraphHelper.client.Users[user.Id].Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
  httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
  httpRequest.Content = GraphHelper.client.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(new User { AccountEnabled = false });
  return batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(httpRequest);
});
var userUpdateResult = await GraphHelper.client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
```

The code below to disable a user already works without batching.

```
var user = new User { AccountEnabled = false };
var userResult = await GraphHelper.client.Users[id].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: Are you sure the **PostAsync(batchRequestContent);** is sending the required properties?

Comment: @abestrad You are right, when I checked with charls proxy, its just sending 
`{"requests": [] }` to  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch` but I can't see what I'm missing when compared to the example in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also able to get same sort of error if I use the lambda operator rather I changed it to foreach loop and added batch requests as shown below.

```
static async Task<BatchResponseContent> BulkUpdate()
{
    var allUsers = await GraphHelper.graphClient.Users.Request().Top(10).Select("id").GetAsync();

    var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
    foreach(var items in allUsers)
    { 
        var httpRequest = GraphHelper.graphClient.Users[items.Id].Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
        httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Patch;
        httpRequest.Content = GraphHelper.graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(new User { AccountEnabled = false });
        batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(httpRequest);
    }
    var userUpdateResult = await GraphHelper.graphClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
    return userUpdateResult;
}
```

This way I am able to add bulk requests to the batchRequestContent variable as you can see in the below picture.

[image: (JSON Data)Body of Batch Request]

**Note**: JSON batch requests are currently [limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#limit-on-batch-size) to 20 individual requests.

Answer (score 1):

For me, what solved it was to add 'headers' field to the request body, and not only to the headers of the request:

```
{'requests': [{
                'id': '1',
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': '/...'
            }, {
                'id': '2',
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': '/...'
            }], 'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue and after a bit of trial/error I figured out that the issue is being caused by the `.Select` method. I noticed that the `batchRequestContent` has a dictionary in it which contains all of the requests to be processed. When adding the requests from within the `.Select` the count never increased.

Converting it to use a standard foreach resolved the issue for me and the `batchRequestContent` successfully showed it's dictionary count increasing as I added new requests to the batch.

```
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
var batchIds = new List<string>();
foreach(var query in queries)
{
    var id = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(query);
    batchIds.Add(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@chris-gunawardena and @shiva-msft-identity I'm wondering if you've any idea what could be going wrong for me, as I'm getting "Invalid batch payload format" when submitting POST method requests to create new items on an SPO list.  The same requests sent individually work no problem, and it seems like an issue with how I'm supplying the body/content.  My issue is over here (and I'm using PowerShell):

[MS Graph batching create list item (SPO) Invalid batch payload format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345199/ms-graph-batching-create-list-item-spo-invalid-batch-payload-format)

Note I see in the JSON Batching video by Microsoft which is on the Docs page, in Graph Explorer they use `"ContentType": "application/json"` whereas the example on the docs page says to supply the "Content-Type" header (note the hyphen).  I've tried using both ContentType and Content-Type for my header (and with application/json) in either case, but it's "Invalid batch payload format" in either case.  If I drop my headers alltogether (the only header in the array of requests is Content-Type (or ContentType)), I then get the error `Write request id : 2 does not contain Content-Type header or body."`.  So it seems like the payload format is at least reasonably close to 'valid'.  It's exactly as I see it in the example on Docs (and in the video from MS).

Comment: FYI, my issue was that I needed to use the -Depth parameter for PowerShell cmdlet ConvertTo-Json in order to properly capture my body's content.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that the allUsers.Select(...) is never fully iterated.

So, either append .ToArray() or, if you got something like MoreLinq, .ForEach() and it'll work.