# MS Graph batching create list item (SPO) Invalid batch payload format

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I did see this same error, in c# has an open question, but I'm using PowerShell and using POST rather than PATCH so I've opened a separate question.

I'm having an issue when using JSON batching, particularly that when I include the header for Content-Type, I receive:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid batch payload format.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-14T00:25:46",
      "request-id": "aa535dbb-efe8-450e-911d-143554ed9027",
      "client-request-id": "aa535dbb-efe8-450e-911d-143554ed9027"
    }
  }
}
```

I first had missed including the headers at all, and was receiving the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write request id : 2 does not contain Content-Type header or body.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-14T00:46:58",
      "request-id": "3601be6d-a861-4947-936b-451cd9de80c3",
      "client-request-id": "3601be6d-a861-4947-936b-451cd9de80c3"
    }
  }
}
```

The body of my HTTP request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch is an array of PSCustomObjects that look like this:

```
id     : 1
method : POST
url    : sites/8c3cb1ef-4116-b0e4-6d0b-25d0f333a4ed/lists/a2b2d34e-6d32-df22-d562-472d3d8385d2/items
body   : {
             "fields":  {
                            "DisplayName":  "user1@contoso.com",
                            "CreatedDateTime":  "2019-10-13",
                            "UserId":  "c963d785-59fc-4384-5e7d-d466=2118e3347",
                            "UserType":  "Guest",
                        }
         }
headers : {
              "Content-Type":  "application/json"
          }
```

I found it odd that when I omit headers, the payload is seemingly OK, and it sees that Content-Type has not been supplied.  Once I add it in, then suddenly payload is not OK.

If I individually perform the requests, all the same data, it's also fine (items create in SPO list without issue).  I feel like this fact confirms that the issue is not with the fields in the body.

I have no issues when batching GET requests (e.g. batching 100's of requests for auditLogs/signIns).  These are essentially the same payload, minus no body/headers, so just id, url, and method.

Has anyone had any experienced this and found a solution?

PS.  The Guid's are all fakes.

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being that I needed to use ConvertTo-Json's -Depth parameter to successfully capture all of my body's content.  It was 5 levels deep (Requests: [ Each Request: { body: { fields: { field names/values } } } ]).

This was only an issue with POST method requests, since a body is then needed, which in this case was for adding SPO list items, which requires the fields: key with children names and values for the list's columns / cells.